# Doctrine Silex query with bound params fails

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, silex, named-parameters

[EDIT] Removed parametrized table name and altered values of order and minimum rating count to distinguish values [/EDIT]

I have a simple table with following create table

```
CREATE TABLE ratings_cache (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    movie_id INT NOT NULL,
    movie_title VARCHAR(128),
    rating DECIMAL(5,4),
    rating_count INT DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Now, I want to query it using Doctrine with some parameters (`app` is Silex application of course):

```
$sql = "
    SELECT ratings_cache.*
    FROM :table_name
    WHERE rating_count > :min_rankings
    ORDER BY rating DESC, rating_count DESC 
    LIMIT :limit";
$stmt = $this->app['db']->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':min_rankings', $this->minRanks);
$stmt->bindValue('limit', $this->limit);
return $stmt->execute()->fetchAll();
```

As you can see the query in this form is simple and it runs smoothly when I run it through Mysql console but when I run the code above I get following error:

```
    An exception occurred while executing '
SELECT *
FROM ratings_cache
WHERE rating_count > :min_rankings
ORDER BY rating DESC, rating_count DESC 
LIMIT :limit' with params [20, 30]:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''30'' at line 5
```

I realize the problem might be with something trivial but I am not very used to Doctrine (usualy prefer handling queries on my own) and simply don't know what might be wrong here...

Comment: Table names cannot be a parameter. [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/182353/7644018)

Comment: @PaulT. Changed query a bit and updated the problem description above

Comment: Actually the problem was with the `:limit` - it needs to be passed as integer so the solution is `$stmt->bindValue('limit', $this->limit, \PDO::PARAM_INT);`